# How to set maximum width for image in iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

[image]I have code

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** My image size is small which i have to expand but not able to apply css for the image in iframe.

Style given is

```
 .ifrmClass
        {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#fff;              
            height:100%;              
            border:none;              
            padding:0px;              
            margin:0px;
        }
```

I'm able to change size in debugging mode.

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>landingpage.jpg (872×360)</title></head><body style="margin: 0px;"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none;width: 100%;height: 90%;" src="../Images/landingpage.jpg"></body></html>
```

Now how can i write the same in my html page ?

Comment: You want to change the size or image or iframe ?

Comment: change the size of image in iframe

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete responsive solution through css only.

I hope finally this solves your problem..

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <!-- a transparent image is preferable -->

    <iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%;background:url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;"> </iframe>
    </div>
    <p>Resize "result" window to notice the effect.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body        {height:100%;}
.h_iframe        {position:relative;}
.h_iframe iframe {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d939e/2/)

Comment: not working ! I do not need image outside my iframe..it would defeat the purpose.. i need < iframe src="../img/name.jpg" />to  be full screen.As u can see the attached image is not full page.

Comment: supposing you have an image which is small and have to expand its size to fit in iframe,how and where will you write the css for it ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the CSS as follows:

```
 .ifrmClass
        {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#fff;              
            height:100%;              
            border:none;              
            padding:0px;              
            margin:0px;
            min-height: 90%; 
            max-height: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/PDKJ4/)

Just add the following code to your css :

```
.ifrmClass {
    min-height: 200px; 
    max-height: 500px; 
}
```

Comment: sorry .. not working! i have added an image.. I need to get the image to max width